# dependency no recorded in the package.json and package-lock.json files

Tags: npm, angular-cli, npm-install

Im using angular cli `1.6.5` and I'm trying to install the dependency `npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@2.0.0 --save`. But this dependency is installed with errors and is not recorded in the package.json and package-lock.json files.

This is what appears to me after executing the previous command:

```
 npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@2.0.0 --save

> fsevents@1.1.3 install /Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.1.3/fse-v1.1.3-node-v64-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.1.3 and node@10.3.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.1.3/fse-v1.1.3-node-v64-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.1.3 and node@10.3.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance


xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
In file included from In file included from ../fsevents.cc:../fsevents.cc6::
6:
../../nan/nan.h:839:18: ../../nan/nan.h:839:18: warning: warning: 'MakeCallback''MakeCallback'  isis  deprecated:deprecated:  UseUse

            MakeCallback(...,MakeCallback(...,  async_context)async_context)  [-Wdeprecated-declarations][-Wdeprecated-declarations]

    return node::MakeCallback(    return node::MakeCallback(

                 ^                 ^

/Users/ferchs/.node-gyp/10.3.0/include/node/node.h:171:1/Users/ferchs/.node-gyp/10.3.0/include/node/node.h:171::1 : notenote: : 'MakeCallback''MakeCallback'

            has hasbeen  explicitlybeen  markedexplicitly deprecated  markedhere 
deprecated here
NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",
^
NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",
^
/Users/ferchs/.node-gyp/10.3.0/include/node/node.h:88:20/Users/ferchs/.node-gyp/10.3.0/include/node/node.h: :88:note20: :expanded  fromnote: 
expanded       frommacro
       macro'NODE_DEPRECATED' 'NODE_DEPRECATED'

    __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
    __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator                   ^

                   ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:854:18: In file included from ../fsevents.ccwarning:: 6:
../../nan/nan.h'MakeCallback':854 :is18:  deprecated: Usewarning: 
      MakeCallback(...,'MakeCallback'  isasync_context)  deprecated: [-Wdeprecated-declarations]Use

MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    return node::MakeCallback(
    return node::MakeCallback(
                 ^                 ^

/Users/ferchs/.node-gyp/10.3.0/include/node/node.h:/Users/ferchs/.node-gyp/10.3.0/include/node/node.h164::1641::1 : note: note: 'MakeCallback'
'MakeCallback'      
has       hasbeen been  explicitlyexplicitly  markedmarked deprecated  deprecatedhere 
here
NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",
^
/Users/ferchs/.node-gyp/10.3.0/include/node/node.h:NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",88:
20: ^
note: expanded from
      macro/Users/ferchs/.node-gyp/10.3.0/include/node/node.h :'NODE_DEPRECATED'88:
20: note: expanded from
      macro     __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator'NODE_DEPRECATED'

                   ^
    __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                   ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:869:18: warning: 'MakeCallback' is deprecated: Use
      MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h    return node::MakeCallback(:869
:18                 ^:
 warning: /Users/ferchs/.node-gyp/10.3.0/include/node/node.h'MakeCallback': 157is: 1deprecated::  Use
      noteMakeCallback(...,:  async_context)'MakeCallback' 
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]      has 
been explicitly marked deprecated here
    return node::MakeCallback(
                 ^
NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",
^/Users/ferchs/.node-gyp/10.3.0/include/node/node.h
:157:1/Users/ferchs/.node-gyp/10.3.0/include/node/node.h:: 88:20note::  'MakeCallback'note
:       hasexpanded  beenfrom 
explicitly       macromarked  'NODE_DEPRECATED'deprecated here

NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",
    __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator^

                   ^
/Users/ferchs/.node-gyp/10.3.0/include/node/node.h:88:20: note: expanded from
      macro 'NODE_DEPRECATED'
    __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                   ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:1478:In file included from 31../fsevents.cc:: 6:
../../nan/nan.hwarning:1478: :31: 'MakeCallback' warningis:  deprecated:'MakeCallback'  Useis 
deprecated:       MakeCallback(...,Use 
async_context)      MakeCallback(...,  [-Wdeprecated-declarations]async_context) 
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    return scope.Escape(node::MakeCallback(
    return scope.Escape(node::MakeCallback(                              ^

                              ^
/Users/ferchs/.node-gyp/10.3.0/include/node/node.h:171:/Users/ferchs/.node-gyp/10.3.0/include/node/node.h:171:11::  note: note: 'MakeCallback'
      'MakeCallback'has
       beenhas  explicitlybeen  markedexplicitly deprecated  markedhere 
deprecated here
NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",
^
/Users/ferchs/.node-gyp/10.3.0/include/node/node.h:88:NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",20:
 ^note: 
expanded from
      macro 'NODE_DEPRECATED'/Users/ferchs/.node-gyp/10.3.0/include/node/node.h:
88:20: note: expanded     __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declaratorfrom

                         ^
macro 'NODE_DEPRECATED'
    __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                   ^
4 warnings generated.
4 warnings generated.
rm: ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o.d.raw: No such file or directory
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:237:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.3.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v10.3.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.3.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.3.0/bin/node" "/Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.3.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.3.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64' (1)

> grpc@1.10.1 install /Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

  COPY /Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/action_after_build.stamp
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.10.1/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.10.1 and node@10.3.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.10.1 and node@10.3.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Hit error Connection closed while downloading tarball file 
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance


xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance


  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
rm: ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o.d.raw: No such file or directory
make: *** [Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o] Error 1
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/avl/avl.o
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:237:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.3.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v10.3.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.3.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.3.0/bin/node" "/Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.3.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.3.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown' (1)
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.oe
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_args.o
../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_args.cc:19:10: fatal error: 
      'grpc/support/port_platform.h' file not found
#include <grpc/support/port_platform.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.░⸩ ⠏ install: info lifecycle grpc@1.10.1~install: Failed to e
make: *** [Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_args.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:237:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.3.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/ferchs/Desktop/OpusClickFrontEnd/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v10.3.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@2.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@2.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@2.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@2.0.0 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.10.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.10.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ferchs/.npm/_logs/2018-07-25T18_00_06_566Z-debug.log
```

I appreciate that someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

According to your posted information,one of the above errors is:

```
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
```

You can solve the problem with the command in your terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```